# SVG Text on Circle - Change text orientation

Tags: css, svg, fonts

I'm adding text along a circle path in an SVG.
I managed to do it but I need to "flip" the upper texts.
[image: Svg text circle]

"Sit amet" and "Dolor" need to be displayed straight like "Lorem" and "Ipsum".
How to achieve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<path style="fill:#EFEFEF;" d="M0,256a256,256 0 1,0 512,0a256,256 0 1,0 -512,0"/>
<path id="textcircle" style="fill:#FAFAFA;" d="M56,256a200,200 0 1,0 400,0a200,200 0 1,0 -400,0"/>
<text style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: 900; font-size:1.2em; fill:#FFAD01;" dy="35" dx="90" >
        <textPath xlink:href="#textcircle">
            Lorem
        </textPath>
</text>
<text style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: 900; font-size:1.2em; fill:#FF7101;" dy="35" dx="420" >
        <textPath xlink:href="#textcircle">
            Ipsum
        </textPath>
</text>
 <text style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: 900; font-size:1.2em; fill:#B6957A;" dy="35" dx="760" >
        <textPath xlink:href="#textcircle">
            Dolor
        </textPath>
</text>
 <text style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: 900; font-size:1.2em; fill:#00B831;" dy="35" dx="1020" >
        <textPath xlink:href="#textcircle">
            Sit amet
        </textPath>
</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you share your css too?

Comment: The css in inline on each text. No additional css.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this you will need to change the direction of the path. In this case I'm using a new path:

```
<path id="textcircle1" stroke="red" fill="none" d="M56,256a200,200 0 1,1 400,0" />
```

Please observe that I've changed the 5th parameter of the arc to 1.

> your code: d="M56,256a200,200 0 1,**0** 400,0 ...
> my code:   d="M56,256a200,200 0 1,**1** 400,0"

Also I'm using only the first arc since the text will fall on thise one.

I've added a red `stroke` to this arc so that you can see it. You can remove the stroke attribute.

Yet another observation is that in order to place the text on yhe path at a certain point you can use the `startOffset` attribute.

I'm keeping your dy attribute but instead of using a dy I could have changed the radius of the circle from 200 to 210 (for example).

Also: please observe that I'm using a `text-anchor="middle"` attribute. In this case the rendered characters are aligned such that the middle of the text string is at the current text position. This is allowing me to set the position of the text preciselly, using `startOffset="80%"` and `startOffset="20%"` i.e at 20% of each end of the path. If you don't want to use the `text-anchor="middle"` you can remove it.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
  <path style="fill:#EFEFEF;" d="M0,256a256,256 0 1,0 512,0a256,256 0 1,0 -512,0" />
  <path id="textcircle" style="fill:#FAFAFA;" d="M56,256a200,200 0 1,0 400,0a200,200 0 1,0 -400,0" />

  <path id="textcircle1" stroke="red" fill="none" d="M56,256a200,200 0 1,1 400,0" />

  <text style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: 900; font-size:1.2em; fill:#FFAD01;" dy="35" dx="90">
    <textPath xlink:href="#textcircle">
      Lorem
    </textPath>
  </text>
  <text style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: 900; font-size:1.2em; fill:#FF7101;" dy="35" dx="420">
    <textPath xlink:href="#textcircle">
      Ipsum
    </textPath>
  </text>

  <g style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: 900; font-size:1.2em;" text-anchor="middle">
    <text fill="#B957A" dy="-10">
      <textPath startOffset="80%" xlink:href="#textcircle1">
        Dolor
      </textPath>
    </text>
    <text style="fill:#00B831;" dy="-10">
      <textPath xlink:href="#textcircle1" startOffset="20%">
        Sit amet
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: That did the trick. Very useful explanation too. Thanks!

Comment: I dont think that it is working. I also tried the double path road but we are hitting the same block. The text is not on the same level: https://jsfiddle.net/tb2koyrd/

Comment: You can change the dy to -25